# Application hangs in memory in android studio after unloading from memory

Tags: android

there. My Application hang in memory in android studio after unloading from memory from recent applications on the device. Second launch of the application opens it in the same place from which I unloaded it from memory. I want my application to be completely destroyed after first upload but I can't achieve this. The application is completely destroyed only after the second upload. How do I get the app to unload the first time? Thanks

The application has only one Activity, I attach its description in the manifest

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```